# Rails - Merge Multi-Select Params into comma-separated string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

I have a select box that allows multiple values, to filter the results on the page. When I select multiple, the Parameters that are submitted look like this:

```
Parameters: {"categories"=>["books", "films"], "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"87"}
```

When I am returned to the page, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000/87/projects?categories%5B%5D=books&categories%5B%5D=films&commit=Submit
```

The URL I would like to return is:

```
http://localhost:3000/87/projects?categories=books,films
```

How can I return these `params[:categories]` as a comma-separated string in the URL? Also, is it possible to remove the "&commit=Submit" from the URL?

Here is my full form code:

```
  <%= form_with url: project_path(@project), local: true, method: :get, skip_enforcing_utf8: true do |form| %>
      <%= form.select(:categories, @categories.map {|category| [category.name,category.slug]}, options = { selected: params[:categories], include_blank: "Select Categories", include_hidden: false }, html_options = { multiple: true }) %>
  <%= form.submit 'Submit' %>
```

Comment: Why would you want it to be in separated format? The url encoded format seems right to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple JS & Rails way to do what you want. I can think of a quick and easy one using rails only: Redirecting the URL you are getting to another route with the data parsed as you want it. Like this -->

Assuming this is your route to **project_path** : `get 'project', to: 'project#reroute', as: :project`

You can go to your `reroute` method in the `project` controller and parse the data you got.

project_controller.rb

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def reroute
    redirect_to your_path(categories: params[:categories].join(','))
  end
end
```

This converts your categories array to a string with your values separated by commas. **It is not an array anymore.** and it also removes "&commit=Submit" like you wanted.

If you dislike the rails routing method, you can also make your submit button to run some JS functions that builds the url string as you want it. For example `<%= submit_tag , :onclick => "return buildUrl();" %>`

Having this said, I must say I agree with Edward's comment, the url encoded format is standard and works out of the box, no need for all the additional rerouting and parsing. Im pretty sure whatever you need the data for can be used with the URL encoded format with proper parsing.